# Sum values in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can I store all of my numberGrades values so they can included in my calculation, I"m new to this so if someone could update my code that would be perfect?

```js
//user input number of grades to be entered
numGrades = prompt("Enter number of grades to be entered: ", ES);

//number of grades to be entered LOOP 
for (index = 1; index <= numGrades; index++) {
  numberGrades = prompt("Enter Grade " + index, ES);
}

//Calculation
gradePointAverage = numberGrades / numGrades;

document.write("Your GPA is " + gradePointAverage + PA);
```

Comment: `prompt` will return a string to `numGrades`, which gets overridden on each loop. Consider converting the prompt return to a number, and use `+=` to add and assign to `numGrades`

Comment: Please change the snippet I made for you to contains ES and PA vars

Comment: I think what you want is to store your grade somewhere or add them all together. What you are doing is getting the last prompt value and divided it by the number of grade

Comment: remove ", ES" from your prompt statement then try

Comment: @Hearner would you know how I would be able to store the grades or add them all together?

Comment: @Ricka yes, i added an answer showing you how it would work (what are ES and index ?)

Comment: @hearner //Declare Variables
var numGrades;  //Number of grades to be entered
var numberGrades; //Number grades
var gradePointAverage; //Average of all grades entered 
var ES = "";  //Empty String
var BR = "<br/>";  //Line Break
var PA = "<p/>";  //Paragraph break
var index;  //loop index

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` method returns a string, so you have to cast it to int or float using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

What you were doing is only getting the last value of your grades. What you want is to sum them all together THEN divide them by the number of grades

There are 2 solutions :

- Store the inputs into an array
- Sum them all together each time a user input a value

```js
// First solution
// Create an array and append each value
numberGrades = [];
for (index = 1; index <= numGrades; index++) {
  valuePrompt = prompt("Enter Grade " + index, ES);
  numberGrades.append(parseFloat(valuePrompt));
}
//Calculation
sumOfGrades = numberGrades.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
gradePointAverage = sumOfGrades / numGrades;

// Second solution
// Add every prompt by the user
numberGrades = 0;
for (index = 1; index <= numGrades; index++) {
  valuePrompt = prompt("Enter Grade " + index, ES);
  numberGrades += parseFloat(valuePrompt));
}
//Calculation
gradePointAverage = numberGrades / numGrades;
```